# Avoid hidden field in the web forms

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page and a modal dialog page. On clicking the save button in the show modal dialog. closes the window and returns a value. Now when the 
control reaches the JavaScript function of the parent window . I wnt to perform some database operation on the basis of this returned ID.

I am using the following approach to utilize this returned value.

1. Keeping it in the hidden field and populating the returned value in hidden control.
2. keeping a hidden button in the parent window, performing the click event when control comes back to JavaScript function of the parent page. Thus in the server side button handler get the value from hidden field and perform database operation on the basis of returned value.

Is this approach fine. Or I can get rid of hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not terribly bad provided the ID returned is not sensitive information that someone can use to modify a record that doesn't belong to him. One can perfectly manipulate this ID on the client side for any other ID and have your logic update a different record from what you intended.

If all you are doing is calling a server side method passing this ID; why don't you do the whole update from the pop-window itself (at that point you already know the ID)?

If the parent window (page) is meant to be updated; you can just perform a normal refresh of the page (ie. use `window.location` to redirect the user to the same page so he can see the update or use `Response.Redirect` to the same page.)

Comment: I have a grid there in parent page and parent page is useing this id and there are some other operations as well

Comment: @StackOverlowUser: Again, your approach is not terribly bad if this information is not sensitive and there's no risk of someone manipulating this ID to hack your app (an intranet app for example). If the only variable here is that ID you return; I don't see how you couldn't possibly do all that other stuff you do on the parent window from the popup window and just have the parent window refresh itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). With AJAX you can communicate with your web server from within your JavaScript code directly. No HTML form posts are required then. You might want to look at frameworks like [JQuery](http://jquery.com). These have easy implementations (cross browser wrappers) to send HTTP requests via AJAX.

Note: I just noticed, you are using ASP.NET. Take a look at [ASP.Net AJAX Page Methods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx).

Comment: I looked into the above suggested article and found that webMethod and static method are required to do so. I think this has a pitfall. I cannot populate the control in this static method as my form controls are not static !!!!!